Acentos con javascript con EXCEL
Hola a todos estoy realizando un codigo javascript donde intento descargar un archivo pero al abrirlo no me esta reconociendo el excel los acentos (tildes) les agradeceria si pueden ayudarme a solucionar este error, la palabra sale de esta manera CÃ©dula y debe verse como Cédula
function generateCSV() {
    // Verifica si al menos un checkbox está marcado
    if (emailValue || cedulaValue) {
        let csvContent = "";

        // Verifica qué checkboxes están seleccionados y agrega los encabezados y valores correspondientes
        if (emailCheckbox.checked && cedulaCheckbox.checked) {
            csvContent += "Email,Cédula\n" + emailValue + ',' + cedulaValue;
        } else if (emailCheckbox.checked) {
            csvContent += "Email\n" + emailValue;
        } else if (cedulaCheckbox.checked) {
            csvContent += "Cédula\n" + cedulaValue;
        }

        // Crea un enlace para descargar el archivo CSV
        const encodedUri = encodeURI('data:text/csv;charset=utf-16,' + csvContent);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "data.csv");
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Agrega el enlace al DOM
        link.click(); // Simula el clic en el enlace para descargar el archivo

        // Elimina el enlace después de la descarga
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
        console.log("Por favor, seleccione al menos un checkbox antes de descargar.");
    }
}


No puedo ayudar mucho, pero intentaré un analisis. Se me ocurren dos causas posibles del error: (1) Estás abriendo el archivo con el encoding equivocado (uno que no acepta tildes) ¿Tal vez ascii? (2) Por alguna razón, el archivo no se genera con el encoding que esperas que tenga, y en su lugar se usa un encoding que no contiene tildes. Suponiendo que el argumento de encodeUri está escrito correctamente, el problema estaría al abrir el archivo.

Debes agregar el tipo de archivo y el UTF-8 antes del encodeURI como lo muestro a continución:
const encodedUri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI(csvContent);

También lo puedes hacer directo desde el setAttribute:
link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI(csvContent));

Espero que te sirva.

Si esta respuesta te ayudó, por favor márcala como aceptada.
